# how to add multiple menu in custom menu widget?

Tags: widgets, menus

how to add multiple menu in custom menu widget? i am using this [theme](http://www.freewpthemes.net/preview/graffiti/). I am new to wordpress and i am unable to sort it out.

Comment: Why not just add another widget below the previous custom menu widget?

Comment: @BrianFegter thanks but i just want to know is there any way that i can add it in a single widget

Answer (score 1):

You can find the WP_Nav_Menu_Widget class in wp-includes/default-widgets.php:1059

1. Simply copy the class (with new name - Example: Foo_Nav_Widget) to your functions.php file.
2. Edit the form method and replicate the select option (with new id/name) and any variables associated.
3. Edit the widget method, replicate any associated variables and call your second nav menu underneath the current nav menu.
4. Register the new widget using register_widget('Foo_Nav_Widget');